# Why doesnt any output show up when I use assert?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I wrote this code, and everything works fine...

```
def lol(n: int):
  a, s = [1], [1]
  output = []
  for i in range(0, n - 1):
    s = a[i:]
    for k in range(0, len(a)):
      s.append(a[k] + s[k])
    a = s
    output.append(s)
  l = [1]

  return l,output
```

and when I do `print(lol(n=10))` my output correctly prints out

```
([1], [[1, 2], [2, 3, 5], [5, 7, 10, 15], [15, 20, 27, 37, 52], [52, 67, 87, 114, 151, 203], [203, 255, 322, 409, 523, 674, 877], [877, 1080, 1335, 1657, 2066, 2589, 3263, 4140], [4140, 5017, 6097, 7432, 9089, 11155, 13744, 17007, 21147], [21147, 25287, 30304, 36401, 43833, 52922, 64077, 77821, 94828, 115975]])
```

However, when I'm doing `assert(lol(n))` nothing happens. I apologize if this is a silly issue but I'm new to this, so yea, can anyone please help me figure what to do to make 'assert' return the output??

Comment: What do you think it should do? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `assert(True)` does *nothing*. `assert(False)` -> error. Your function output is a tuple of two elements, which is truthy.

Comment: @Reti43 ohhh okay okay.. yea I was confused sorry. I thought assert does the same as print. My bad.. thabks for ur explaination n clarification

Comment: "I thought assert does the same as print." Why? How did you hear that there is such a thing as `assert` at all, and *what did that source tell you* about it?

Answer (score 2):

To use assert correctly you need check the condition:

```
assert 1 == 2 # raise AssertionError
assert 5 > 3 # do not raise
```

in your case `lol(n=10)` evaluates to True, so nothing raises